# Currying in Haskell with 2+ arguments

Tags: haskell, currying, pointfree, tacit-programming

I'm starting to learn Haskell so I need to understand currying also (it's the first time I've seen this technique too). I think I get how it works in some cases where the currification only "eliminates" one of the parameters. Like in the next example where I'm trying to calculate the product of 4 numbers.
This is the uncurried function:

```
prod :: Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer
prod x y z t = x * y * z * t
```

This is the curried function:

```
prod' :: Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer
prod' x y z = (*) (x*y*z)
```

But I don't understand how could I continue this dynamic and do for example the same function with only two arguments and so on:

```
prod'' :: Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer
prod'' x y =
```

Comment: First you need to realize that every function in Haskell has at most one argument.

Comment: @bipll and [at least](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell) one argument. IOW, every function has _exactly_ one argument.

Comment: @leftaroundabout `zero = 0`

Comment: @bipll that's not a function. there's no `->` in `zero`'s type.

Answer (score 5):

> This is the uncurried function:
>
> ```
> prod :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
> prod x y z t = x * y * z * t
> ```

This is *already* a curried function. In fact all functions in Haskell are automatically curried. Indeed, you here wrote a function that looks like:

```
prod :: Integer -> (Integer -> (Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)))
```

Haskell will thus produce a function that looks like:

```
prod :: Integer -> (Integer -> (Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)))
prod = \x -> (\y -> (\z -> (\t -> x * y * z * t)))
```

Indeed, we can for example generate such function:

```
prod2 = prod 2
```

This will have type:

```
prod2 :: Integer -> (Integer -> (Integer -> Integer))
prod2 = prod 2
```

and we can continue with:

```
prod2_4 :: Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)
prod2_4 = prod2 4
```

and eventually:

```
prod2_4_6 :: Integer -> Integer
prod2_4_6 = prod2_4 6
```

**EDIT**

The function `prod'` with:

```
prod'' x y = (*) ((*) (x*y))
```

Since that means you multiply `(*) (x*y)` with the next parameter. But `(*) (x*y)` is a function. You can only multiply numbers. Strictly speaking you can make functions numbers. But the Haskell compiler thus complains that:

```
Prelude> prod'' x y = (*) ((*) (x*y))

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        prod'' :: forall a.
                  (Num (a -> a), Num a) =>
                  a -> a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

It thus says that you here aim to perform an operation with a function `a -> a` as first operand, but that this function is not an instance of the `Num` typeclass.

Comment: that's not what is asked in the question, though.

Comment: @WillNess: it asks to make a curried function, not a point-free one.

Comment: look at the types. :) it's not the first time an asker is confused about the terminology.

Comment: @WillNess: I honestly don't see what the types do here :) especially since Haskell's syntax already is curried, and making something point-free should of course not alter the types.

Comment: the types of `prod'` and `prod''` are both `Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer`. the types of your partially applied examples are different. so I interpreted this as OP's confusion about terminology.

Comment: Furthermore I don't see any proof of confusion with point-free either. It is not strange that people that come from for example JavaScript, think that `prod x y z t = ...` is equivalent to `func prod(x, y, z, y) { ... }`, and thus aim to make something like `prod(x) { ... }` to do it. My Occam's razor sees that as a more logical explanation (since Haskell's syntax is a bit "overconvenient" by some).

Comment: @WillNess: of course they are, these are only to demonstrate that we can do currying. It thus demonstrates that we can call `prod 2` in the first place. Since in JavaScript (to continue on the example), calling `prod(2)` on a `func prod (x, y, z, t) { ... }` would usually end up with an error.

Comment: a nitpick: we don't "do" currying, we use it; Haskell *the language* is what's curried -- as you write, "all functions in Haskell are [already and irrevocably --wn] automatically curried". (the usual talk of `(a,b)->c ==> a->b->c` being "currying" just adds to the confusion.)

Comment: I get that Haskell actually only receives one argument and is returning functions until it reaches the last argument and then returns the actual value. That's why I thought about doing it like this but its not working and I can't understand why:                                                                                           
    prod'' :: Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer
    prod'' x y = (*) ((*) (x*y))

Comment: @moliverac8: well you can make it entirely "pointfree" with `prod = ((((*) .) . (*)) .) . (*)`, or with one argument, you can use `prod x = ((*) .) . (*) . (x *)`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what that term "pointfree" means. I'll investigate it

Comment: @moliverac8 "[tag:pointfree]" means "without explicit arguments", like your `prod'` does not name `t`, and `prod''` does not name `t` nor `z`. see the [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pointfree/info). another name for it is "[tag:tacit-programming]" (judging from that tag's description).

Answer (score 4):

What you have is

```
prod x y z t  =    x * y * z * t
              =   (x * y * z) * t
              =  (*) (x * y * z) t
```

Hence by *eta reduction* (where we replace `foo x = bar x` with `foo = bar`)

```
prod x y z    =  (*) (x * y * z)
              =  (*) ( (x * y) * z )
              =  (*) ( (*) (x * y) z )
              =  ((*) . (*) (x * y)) z
```

so that by eta reduction again,

```
prod x y      =   (*) . (*) (x * y)
```

Here `(.)` is the function composition operator, defined as

```
(f . g) x  =  f (g x)
```

What you're asking about is known as *point-free style*. "Point-free" means "without explicitly mentioning the [implied] arguments" ("point" is a mathematician's jargon for "argument" here).

"Currying" is an orthogonal issue, although Haskell being a curried *language* makes such definitions -- and partial application ones, shown in Willem's answer -- easier to write. "Currying" means functions take their arguments one at a time, so it is easy to partially apply a function to a value.

We can continue the process of pulling the last argument *out* so it can be eliminated by eta reduction further. But it usually rapidly leads to more and more obfuscated code, like `prod = ((((*) .) . (*)) .) . (*)`.

That's because written code is a one-dimensional encoding of an inherently two-dimensional (or even higher-dimensional) computational graph structure,

```
  prod =           
                  /
                 *
                / \
               *   
              / \
         <-- *   
              \
```

You can experiment with it [here](http://pointfree.io/). E.g., if `(*)` were right-associative, we'd get even more convoluted code

```
\x y z t -> x * (y * (z * t))
==
(. ((. (*)) . (.) . (*))) . (.) . (.) . (*)
```

representing just as clear-looking, just slightly rearranged, graph structure

```
              / 
         <-- *   
              \ /
               *
                \ /
                 *
                  \
```